# App Not Working in Api 19 Android KitKat 4.4

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, data-binding

**The Same app wok in android lollipop but not working in android kitkat
I Thinks the error is in data binding code**

Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gph.gph, PID: 2610
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
        at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.inflateInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:1366)
        at com.gph.geeksperhour.databinding.LayoutProjectsItemBinding.inflate(LayoutProjectsItemBinding.java:80)
        at com.gph.geeksperhour.databinding.LayoutProjectsItemBinding.inflate(LayoutProjectsItemBinding.java:66)
        at com.gph.geeksperhour.adapter.WordsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(WordsAdapter.java:64)
        at com.gph.geeksperhour.adapter.WordsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(WordsAdapter.java:27)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6942)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5997)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5993)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2227)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1558)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1518)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:613)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4029)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3746)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4299)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:625)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1193)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:880)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:899)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1193)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:880)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.wid
```

Here's my Code

```
     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp">

            <TextView                     *******************************
                android:id="@+id/txt_project_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@{word.projectName}"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"

                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="@font/muli"/>
<!--            android:paddingTop="18dp"
android:textSize="16sp"-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_projects_client_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@{word.projectDetail}"  *******************

                android:fontFamily="@font/muli_light"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
            <!--android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"-->
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="right">

                <!--<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivNewMessages"
                    android:layout_width="14dp"
                    android:layout_height="14dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/bubble"
                    android:visibility="@{word.hasNewMessages ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>-->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                    android:paddingRight="6dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@{`` + word.unreadMessageCount}"
                    android:visibility="@{word.unreadMessageCount>0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:background="@drawable/bubble"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/muli_light"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="@{``+word.projectStartingDateMMMDDYYYY}"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/muli_light"/>



                <!--            android:visibility="@{word.messageSentByMe ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"-->
            </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It Show the Errors in line on which a have put ** stars ....

Comment: are you using Vector drawables in your `xml` layout

Comment: No, not in this layout

Comment: check `tvCount`TextView I think the error is there

Comment: for what type of problem to check for in tvcount.

Comment: the LogCat shows the error lines where i have put Stars(**)

Comment: you are using data binding right? then where is the the data `tag` which have the `word` class